# error -201 ejecutando un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un formulario el cual se permite descargar a excel, la forma en como lo estoy haciendo es por medio de una tabla externa, para esto utilizo un procedimiento. pero al ejecutar mi formulario con todos los campos para mostrar me genera un error (-201) error de sintaxis.

este es el procedimiento.

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE prc_datos_external(
             '/mnt/nfs/consultas_portal_tmp/".$strNombrearchivo."'
            ,'tmpDownloadFile'
            ,'$separador'
            ,2
            ,'valor LVARCHAR(4000)'
            ,\"SELECT valor FROM (SELECT $elsel valor FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1 "
              ." UNION ALL SELECT $elseln valor FROM tmp_resumen2)\"
            ,1);";
```

Cuando se ejecuta, en mi formulario php estoy ralizando las siguientes validaciones. esto es para evitar errores de datos y realice conversiones de algunos datos  que son tipo fecha en varchar, para evitar errores en el proceso.

```
    introducir el código aquí

$ar_sel = split(',', $selcampos);
        $arF = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($ar_sel); $i++) { 
            $ar_sel[$i] = trim($ar_sel[$i]);
            if (strpos($ar_sel[$i], '(') === false && strpos($ar_sel[$i], ')') === false) {
                if (strpos($ar_sel[$i], 'sum(') === false && strpos($ar_sel[$i], 'count(') === false) {

                    if(   $ar_sel[$i] == 'f_factura' || $ar_sel[$i] == 'f_creacion' || $ar_sel[$i] == 'f_sistema'
                        || $ar_sel[$i] == 't_sistema' || $ar_sel[$i] == 'c_cajero') 
                    {
                        $arF[$i] = "".$ar_sel[$i]."::VARCHAR(40),''))";
                    } 
                    else if(   $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_linea'      && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_categoria' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_subcategoria'  && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_segmento' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_clasificacion' && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_referencia_prov' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_producto'      && $ar_sel[$i] != 'c_talla' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_talla'         && $ar_sel[$i] != 'c_color_proveedor' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_color_proveedor' && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_coleccion' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_proveedor'     && $ar_sel[$i] != 'ubicacion' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_presentacion'  && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_grupo' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_ciudad'        && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_marca' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'nombre'          && $ar_sel[$i] != 'nombre_completo' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_tipo_venta'    && $ar_sel[$i] != 'st_mode_transacction' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'us_creacion'     && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_lista_precio' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_cliente'       && $ar_sel[$i] != 'tipo_factura' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'anulado'         && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_iva' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_sector'        && $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_almacen' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'c_barra'         && $ar_sel[$i] != 'c_unidad_medida' 
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'cs_observacion'  && $ar_sel[$i] != 'observacion'
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'observacion_an'  && $ar_sel[$i] != 'prefijo'
                        &&  $ar_sel[$i] != 'd_remitente') 
                    { 
                        $arF[$i] = "ROUND(".$ar_sel[$i].",".trim($valorDecimal).")::VARCHAR(40),''))";
                    }else {
                        $arF[$i] = $ar_sel[$i]  . ",''))";
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

$elseln  = implode(" || '".$separador."' || TRIM(NVL(", $arF);
        $ar_sel = split(', ', $elseln);

```
    $elseln  = implode(" || '".$separador."' || ", $ar_sel);
    $elseln  = 'TRIM(NVL(' . $elseln;
```

cuando se realiza la consulta genera error 201 y no me genera el archivo
EXECUTE PROCEDURE prc_datos_external( '/mnt/nfs/consultas_portal_tmp/ct060900051217105137.csv' ,'tmpDownloadFile' ,';' ,2 ,'valor LVARCHAR(4000)' ,"SELECT valor FROM (SELECT 'c_linea; d_linea; c_categoria; d_categoria; c_subcategoria; d_subcategoria; c_segmento; d_segmento; c_sector; d_sector; c_almacen; d_almacen; c_clasificacion; d_clasificacion; c_producto; d_producto; c_barra; sku; c_talla; d_talla; c_color_proveedor; d_color_proveedor; c_coleccion; d_coleccion; d_presentacion; ubicacion; c_grupo; d_grupo; c_ciudad; d_ciudad; c_marca; d_marca; f_creacion; c_vendedor; nombre; cc_cliente ; nombre_completo; c_tipo_venta; d_tipo_venta; caja; d_caja; factura; f_factura; vr_margen ; vr_margen_utilidad ; f_sistema; t_sistema; c_lista_precio; d_lista_precio; us_creacion; preciomae; d_referencia_prov; precio_venta_un; tipo_factura; anulado; c_iva; d_iva; doc_referencia; cs_observacion; observacion; observacion_an; prefijo; c_cajero ; d_remitente; st_mode_transacction; vr_bruto; vr_neto; vr_descuento; vr_descuento_por; vr_iva; cn_venta' valor FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1 UNION ALL SELECT TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_linea,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_linea,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_categoria,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_categoria,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_subcategoria,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_subcategoria,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_segmento,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_segmento,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_sector,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_sector,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_almacen,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_almacen,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_clasificacion,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_clasificacion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_producto,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_producto,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(c_barra,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(sku,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(c_talla,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_talla,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(c_color_proveedor,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_color_proveedor,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_coleccion,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_coleccion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_presentacion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ubicacion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_grupo,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_grupo,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_ciudad,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_ciudad,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_marca,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_marca,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(f_creacion::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_vendedor,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(nombre,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(cc_cliente,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(nombre_completo,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_tipo_venta,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_tipo_venta,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(caja,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(d_caja,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(factura,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(f_factura::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_margen,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_margen_utilidad,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(f_sistema::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(t_sistema::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_lista_precio,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_lista_precio,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(us_creacion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(preciomae,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_referencia_prov,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(precio_venta_un,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(tipo_factura,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(anulado,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(c_iva,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_iva,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(doc_referencia,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(cs_observacion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(observacion,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(observacion_an,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(prefijo,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(c_cajero::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(d_remitente,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(st_mode_transacction,'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_bruto,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_neto,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_descuento,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_descuento_por,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(vr_iva,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) || ';' || TRIM(NVL(ROUND(cn_venta,0)::VARCHAR(40),'')) valor FROM tmp_resumen2)" ,1);
Warning: ifx_query() [function.ifx-query]: Execute immediate fails : E [SQLSTATE=42 000 SQLCODE=-201] in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/fuentes_dllo/conexiones/informix.php on line 10

Comment: Eso es bastante código. Creo que tu estás en la mejor posición de ir reduciendo el código hasta poder aíslar el problema. Hay una explicación sobre esta técnica aquí: [mcve].

Comment: la cuenstion es que solo me genera el error si selecciono todos los campos que esta en la pregunta, pero si lo genero con -4 campos, si me genera la consulta correctamente.  hay alguna condición de que solo permita hasta cierto tamaño de caracteres?...